# N''' prefix is added by default while executing Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

While executing stored procedure, I'm passing 4 arguments. After passing the arguments through GUI mode, I'm seeing that some prefixes has been added by the sql itself.

```
USE [du_Attendance]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GET_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_FOR_FACULTY]
        @startdate = '1/9/2018',
        @enddate = '1/12/2018',
        @coursecode = N'''BSCCS''',
        @subjectcode = N'''CSHT101'''

SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'

GO
```

So when I am removing the N'', it's giving me an error saying Invalid column name 'BSCCS'. What does it mean ?

Full Stored Procedure -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_FOR_FACULTY
@startdate DATE,  
@enddate DATE,
@coursecode varchar(10),
@subjectcode varchar(10)


AS BEGIN

DECLARE @cols as varchar(2000);
DECLARE @cols_select as varchar(MAX);
declare @col varchar(20)
declare @cols_copy varchar(100)
DECLARE @query as varchar(MAX);

WITH cte (startdate)
AS 
(SELECT
        @startdate AS startdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DD, 1, startdate) AS startdate
    FROM cte
    WHERE startdate < @enddate
)
select c.startdate
into #tempDates
from cte c
where datename(weekday, c.startdate) <> 'Sunday';

SELECT
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(CHAR(6),startdate, 106))
        FROM #tempDates
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

select @cols_copy = replace(@cols, ',', '')

select @cols_select = SUBSTRING(@cols_select, 2, len(@cols_select) - 1)


SET @query = 'SELECT RollNo,FirstName,LastName, ' + dbo.fn_convert_cols(@cols) + ' from 
             (
                select S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName,
                D.startdate,
                convert(CHAR(6), startdate, 106) PivotDate
                from #tempDates D,Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
                where convert(CHAR(6), D.startdate, 106) = convert(CHAR(6), A.Date, 106) and A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and A.EnrollmentNo=U.userID and A.CourseCode=' + @coursecode + ' and A.SubjectCode =' + @subjectcode + '
            ) x
           pivot 
           (
                count(startdate)
                for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
           ) p '

EXECUTE (@query)
drop table #tempDates
END
```

The problem with this is I am passing the parameters from C# code so only 'BSCCS' is passed into the stored procedure resulting in the above mentioned error.

C# Code -

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Constants.getAttendanceForFaculty, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coursecode", courseCode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectcode", subCode);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
```

Comment: What does the rest of the procedure do?

Comment: First, it generates the dates between '@startdate' and '@enddate' and store it in the temp table and then get the data from another table, keeping the dates generated from the temp table as columns and filing the data respectively.

Comment: Please post a C# repro.  It looks like you may be surrounding your parameter value with an extra set of ''.

Comment: I added the C# code but it is working smooth with @coursecode = N'''BSCCS'''. As soon as I remove the N'' '', it gives the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your dynamic query like this, otherwise - because of dynamic query - SQL executes your parameters like columns.

I changed

`A.CourseCode=' + @coursecode + ' and A.SubjectCode =' + @subjectcode + '`

to this

`A.CourseCode=''' + @coursecode + ''' and A.SubjectCode =''' + @subjectcode + '''`

```
SET @query = 'SELECT RollNo,FirstName,LastName, ' + dbo.fn_convert_cols(@cols) + ' from 
             (
                select S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName,
                D.startdate,
                convert(CHAR(6), startdate, 106) PivotDate
                from #tempDates D,Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
                where convert(CHAR(6), D.startdate, 106) = convert(CHAR(6), A.Date, 106) and A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and A.EnrollmentNo=U.userID and A.CourseCode=''' + @coursecode + ''' and A.SubjectCode =''' + @subjectcode + '''
            ) x
           pivot 
           (
                count(startdate)
                for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
           ) p '
```

Comment: Ah.. quotes. These quotes troubled me for 2 hours straight. Btw if I am executing the stored procedure directly, sql is still adding prefix N'' and suffix ''. What it is doing this ?

Comment: single quote automatically converts to double quotes by .net. Actually, it is not adding N'' or  '', it just converts ' chars to this ''

Comment: While there is no way to fix the pivot columns, you really should be passing proper, strongly-typed parameters for course code and subject code. The only benefit you get from appending those as simple strings is if you are moonlighting as a security consultant and *want* SQL injection to happen.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It is just a prototype for my minor project for now. Obviously going to prepare a proper format for everything if it had to go live.

Comment: @SuyashGupta But why not just always do it the right way? Habits are good. Excuses aren't. :-)

Comment: Because it's a university project and I don't know yet what will be the format of the codes.